# How to know if page was closed / refreshed / 'go back' was pressed in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the function `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {...}`
In the function, I want to know which action triggered the listener.

I tried to use this method with no success:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
     if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        document.write('Window was refreshed!');
     } 
     else {
        document.write('Window was closed!');
     }
});
```

Any action (refresh/close/'go back') triggers the `else` part... what am I doing wrong?

Alternative method would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you always trigger the `else` handler, because of the way `peformance.navigation` works.
Even if you write it in the `beforeunload` handler, it still runs on your **current** document, not the one you are loading, so it will output the `PerformanceNavigation` object that contains info on how you opened your **current** page, and not the one you are trying to navigate to.

As to the part in your question about deteciting whatever method user used to leave the page, i don't think thats possible at the moment, not without usage of 'dirty' hacks/workarounds (detecting which button has user clicked, detecting keyboard events, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

use [router events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) You can subscribe in your app.component like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events
    .subscribe((event) => {
      // example: NavigationStart, RoutesRecognized, NavigationEnd
      console.log(event);
    });
}
```